# Sending href from a button with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code here, what i am trying to achieve is when the button is pressed  `<th>Delete</th>` i want to redirect to  `'<a href="/deleteAjax/"  + data[i].jobId` in this case i want when edit button is pressed example i press a data with id 3 url should be /deteleAjax/3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '/jsonDiqka',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i].jobId + '</td><td>' + data[i].lokacioni + '</td><td>' + data[i].kategoria + '</td><td>' + '<a href="/deleteAjax/"  + data[i].jobId  +  target="_parent"><button id="clickID">Click me !</button></a>' + '</td></tr>');
                $('#myTable').append(row);

            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

But when the button is being pressed the id is not showing up only `/deleteAjax/`

Comment: In the function you could do something likr $.("clickID").href = "whatever you want". Don't know for sure wheter the syntax is correct, vut somehow it is possible to set the href attribute via javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the way you wrote your anchor tag is wrong as the href only include /deleteAjax/.

If your button shows /deleteAjax/ with your previous code than this should put the job id in there. Just be careful where to put the quotation when using the HTML tag inside Jquery. That is probably the mistake.

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i].jobId + '</td><td>' + data[i].lokacioni + '</td><td>' + data[i].kategoria + '</td><td>' + '<a href="/deleteAjax/' + data[i].jobId + '"   target="_parent"><button id="clickID">Click me !</button></a>' + '</td></tr>');
                $('#myTable').append(row);

            }
```